# How can I implement an bad list in a WebService using PHP

Tags: php, linux, firewall

I have an public API how needs authentication and block all users who try brute force...

I'm thinking in log all operations in /var/log/auth.log using [syslog](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php), and configure [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/) to add IP from user in deny list of iptables.

This is a good solution? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing your log entries in a format similar to many other services, than there's quite a few different services that you could use to block access to your system:

- [DenyHosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/)
- [Sshguard](http://www.sshguard.net/)
- [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/)

Sshguard seems quite nice as it has modular backends and  supports quite a range of different log formats including: ssh, sendmail, exim, dovecot, pureftpd, and vsftpd.